# How to set HTTP header in vue-cli?

Tags: http, vue.js, header, vue-cli

I want to set custom header in vue-cli.

The version of vue is 2.5.2.

I tried in main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.http.headers.common['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

But it returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to install vue-resource or vue-axios library to make this work and make REST calls.

Please install and try again.

https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry my example source code confused you. What I want to do is not to solve CORS problem.

Comment: Yes whatever the problem but there is nothing inbuilt "http" variable in Vue. You have to install either of these libraries I listed. Did you already installed and it's not working ? If that is the case then let me know else please if not installed please install and try.

Comment: Ok install vue-resource if not installed yet and then add following lines to main.js below "import router from './router'" 
`import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource)`; It should work fine then.

Comment: @JeongyongLee Great. Please accept my answer as the solution for your problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The question is clear (but could use some editing) and has nothing to do with making http requests from vue, but rather sending a custom header when using the vue-cli dev server (serve command), this is what the OP is looking for, same as me and in no way what this answer is addressing

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`devServer`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver) option of your `vue.config.js` which just proxies it to webpack

To set headers:

```js
devServer: {
   headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" }
}
```